# element attributes missing when parsing XML with iterparse/lxml/python 2

Tags: python, xml, lxml, iterparse

Here's my use case:
I have a potentially large XML file, and I want to output the frequency of all the unique structural variations of a given element type. Element attributes should be included as part of the uniqueness test. The output should sort the variations by frequency.

Here's a trivial input example, with 4 entries for automobile:

```
<automobile>
    <mileage>20192</mileage>
    <year>2005</year>
    <user_defined name="color">red</user_defined>
</automobile>
<automobile>
    <mileage>1098</mileage>
    <year>2018</year>
    <user_defined name="color">blue</user_defined>
</automobile>
<automobile>
    <mileage>17964</mileage>
    <year>2012</year>
    <user_defined name="title_status">salvage</user_defined>
</automobile>
<automobile>
    <mileage>198026</mileage>
    <year>1990</year>
</automobile>
```

The output I expect would look like this:

```
<automobile automobile_frequency="2">
    <mileage />
    <year />
    <user_defined name="color" />
</automobile>
<automobile automobile_frequency="1">
    <mileage />
    <year />
    <user_defined name="title_status" />
</automobile>
<automobile automobile_frequency="1">
    <mileage />
    <year />
</automobile>
```

I've implemented the code using iterparse, but when it's processing the elements, the attributes do not exist in the element. The code logic appears to be correct, but attributes simply don't exist; they are not written in the output, and they are not present for the uniqueness test. Per the above input example, this is what I get on output:

```
<root>
  <automobile automobile_frequency="3">
    <mileage/>
    <year/>
    <user_defined/>
  </automobile>
  <automobile automobile_frequency="1">
    <mileage/>
    <year/>
  </automobile>
</root>
```

The usage is:

```
xplore.py input.xml node_to_explore
```

In the above example, I used:

```
xplore.py trivial.xml automobile
```

Here's the source:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime


# global node signature map
structure_map = {}
# global code frequency map
frequency_map = {}
# output tree
tmp_root = etree.Element("tmp_root")


def process_element(el):
    global target
    if el.tag != target:
        return
    # get the structure of the element
    structure = get_structure(el)
    global structure_map
    structure_key = etree.tostring(structure, pretty_print=True)
    if structure_key not in structure_map.keys():
        # add signature to structure map
        structure_map[structure_key] = structure
        # add node to output
        global tmp_root
        tmp_root.append(structure)
        # add signature to frequency map
        frequency_map[structure_key] = 1
    else:
        # increment frequency map
        frequency_map[structure_key] += 1


# returns a unique string representing the structure of the node
# including attributes
def get_structure(el):
    # create new element for the return value
    ret = etree.Element(el.tag)
    # get attributes
    attribute_keys = el.attrib.keys()
    for attribute_key in attribute_keys:
        ret.set(attribute_key, el.get(attribute_key))
    # check for children
    children = list(el)
    for child in children:
        ret.append(get_structure(child))
    return ret


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Must specify an XML file for processing, as well as an element type!"
    exit(0)

# Get XML file
xml = sys.argv[1]
# Get output file name
output_file = xml[0:xml.rindex(".")]+".txt"
# get target element type to evaluate
target = sys.argv[2]
# mark start
startTime = datetime.now()
# Parse XML

print '==========================='
print 'Parsing XML'
print '==========================='
context = etree.iterparse(xml, events=('end',))
for event, element in context:
    process_element(element)
    element.clear()
# create tree sorted by frequency
ranked = sorted(frequency_map.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
root = etree.Element("root")
for item in ranked:
    structure = structure_map[item[0]]
    structure.set(target+"_frequency", str(item[1]))
    root.append(structure)
# pretty print root
out = open(output_file, 'w')
out.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
# output run time
time = datetime.now() - startTime
reg3 = re.compile("\\d+:\\d(\\d:\\d+\\.\\d{4})")
time = re.search(reg3, unicode(time))
time = "Runtime: %ss" % (time.group(1).encode("utf-8"))
print(time)
```

In the debugger, I can clearly see that the attributes are missing from elements in the calls to get_structure. Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It was my understanding that using iterparse in this way, one should only use the end event. Per this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29689256/lxml-etree-iterparse-and-parsing-element-completely According to the documentation, "Note that the text, tail, and children of an Element are not necessarily present yet when receiving the start event. Only the end event guarantees that the Element has been parsed completely."

Comment: It turns out, the issue was with where I called element.clear(). After moving it to the end of get_structure, everything behaved as expected. My biggest frustration in this process was trying to find a definitive list of fields that are supposed to be available at the start event. The best I could find was this message from Fredrik Lundh to the XML-SIG list in 2005: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/xml-sig/2005-January/010838.html

Comment: A summary of Fredrik Lundh’s message, in case that link dies some time in the future:

start event:
elem.tag
    elem.attrib
    tags and attributes for parent elements (use a stack if you need to track them)

end event includes the above, plus:

    elem.text
    elem[:] (i.e. the children)
    complete contents for all children (including the tail)
    (not elem.tail) (but all child tails)

Comment: Was it not sufficient to state that the issue was a logic error on my part, and moving the call to element.clear() resolved the issue? I also included the best reference I could find on which element attributes are available during the start and end events, which was key to finding the solution. Please note that the more complete version of my explanation exceeded the length limit for comments. For example, I spent a lot of time exploring your initial comment that the attributes may only be available during the start event, but there is not enough space in a comment to explain it.

Comment: Succinct answer: element attributes are NOT missing during end event processing when using lxml's iterparse. If you are not seeing attributes during the processing of end events, either there were no attributes for that element, or you may have inadvertently invoked the clear() method on that element prior to processing its end event.

Answer (score 0):

The data:

```xml
<root>
    <automobile>
        <mileage>20192</mileage>
        <year>2005</year>
        <user_defined name="color">red</user_defined>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
        <mileage>1098</mileage>
        <year>2018</year>
        <user_defined name="color">blue</user_defined>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
        <mileage>17964</mileage>
        <year>2012</year>
        <user_defined name="title_status">salvage</user_defined>
    </automobile>
    <automobile>
        <mileage>198026</mileage>
        <year>1990</year>
    </automobile>
</root>
```

The code:

```py
from lxml import etree
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime


# global node signature map
structure_map = {}
# global code frequency map
frequency_map = {}
# output tree
tmp_root = etree.Element("tmp_root")


def process_element(el):
    # get the structure of the element
    structure = get_structure(el)
    global structure_map
    structure_key = etree.tostring(structure, pretty_print=True)
    if structure_key not in structure_map.keys():
        # add signature to structure map
        structure_map[structure_key] = structure
        # add node to output
        global tmp_root
        tmp_root.append(structure)
        # add signature to frequency map
        frequency_map[structure_key] = 1
    else:
        # increment frequency map
        frequency_map[structure_key] += 1


# returns a unique string representing the structure of the node
# including attributes
def get_structure(el):
    # create new element for the return value
    ret = etree.Element(el.tag)
    # get attributes
    attribute_keys = el.attrib.keys()
    for attribute_key in attribute_keys:
        ret.set(attribute_key, el.get(attribute_key))
    # check for children
    children = list(el)
    for child in children:
        ret.append(get_structure(child))
    return ret


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Must specify an XML file for processing, as well as an element type!"
    exit(0)

# Get XML file
xml = sys.argv[1]
# Get output file name
output_file = xml[0:xml.rindex(".")]+".txt"
# get target element type to evaluate
target = sys.argv[2]
# mark start
startTime = datetime.now()
# Parse XML

print '==========================='
print 'Parsing XML'
print '==========================='
context = etree.iterparse(xml, events=('end',))
element_to_clear = []
for event, element in context:
    element_to_clear.append(element)
    global target
    if element.tag == target:
        process_element(element)
        for ele in element_to_clear:
            ele.clear()
        element_to_clear = []
# create tree sorted by frequency
ranked = sorted(frequency_map.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
root = etree.Element("root")
for item in ranked:
    structure = structure_map[item[0]]
    structure.set(target+"_frequency", str(item[1]))
    root.append(structure)
# pretty print root
out = open(output_file, 'w')
out.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
# output run time
time = datetime.now() - startTime
reg3 = re.compile("\\d+:\\d(\\d:\\d+\\.\\d{4})")
time = re.search(reg3, unicode(time))
time = "Runtime: %ss" % (time.group(1).encode("utf-8"))
print(time)
```

The command: `xplore.py trivial.xml automobile`